# Stop ModalPopupExtender from coming up due to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

ASP.net project using ajax (.net 2.0).
I've got a modalpopupextender that is linked to an image button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibStartNow" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/StartNow.gif" 
    ToolTip="Save expense report header and start now!" CausesValidation="False" 
    OnClientClick="CheckReason(); NoPrompt();" />
```

Notice the OnClientClick event there is a js function called CheckReason, this function simply checks a textbox called reason to see if anyone has entered anything.  If they haven't I do NOT want the ModalPopupExtender to actually open.

Here is that JavaScript function although ugly :)

```
function CheckReason()
{
    var txtReason = document.getElementById('txtReason');
    var txtReasonVal = txtReason.value;
    if (txtReasonVal.length > 0 && txtReasonVal != 'Enter the reason for creating this expense report...')
    { 
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        txtReason.style.borderStyle='solid';
        txtReason.style.borderColor='red';
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue is even if I hit the else and return false, the modal popup extender still opens the modal popup. I need it so that it does not open up the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
OnClientClick="javascript:var ret = CheckReason(); NoPrompt(); return ret;"
```

Comment: No that doesnt do it.  I think this is more of an issue with how the modalpopupextender works as there is nothing wrong with your code.